# What files and/or directories can be removed from a Windows XP install without breaking anything?

Tags: windows-xp, cleaning

This is *after* installation (I haven't got the option of **nLite** or similar tools to slim the install disc).

I'll be taking a hard disk image (using Norton Ghost running off a BartPE CD). To be exact, I'm running XP SP3.

To clean and minimise the size of the image, I **remove any apps I don't need**, **switch off hibernation** and then reboot into BartPE. In BartPE, I then usually delete the **pagefile.sys**, clear the **temp directories**, **HotFix uninstallers** and **Windows Updates installers** (`J:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution`) using **CCleaner** and finally defrag using **MyDefrag** to pull everything together.

Are there any other specific directories/files (Windows or otherwise) I can safely remove without causing any headaches?

- `c:\WINDOWS\ie8updates` ?
- `c:\WINDOWS\Downloaded Installations` ?
- etc.

Any experience of your suggested deletions would be useful too.

Answer (score 2):

As Tofystedeth remarks, rollback information for Windows Update is kept in `C:\Windows` in hidden folders with names `$NtUninstallKB#######$` which, if the system is stable with those patches can be deleted.

If your XP system is not vanilla SP3, then this directory can be quite large.

Comment: winsxs is for Side-by-Side Assembly which lets programs that require a specific version of a DLL use it even if there is a newer version installed on the system.  Rollback information for Windows Update is kept in C:\Windows in hidden folders with names $NtUninstallKB#######$ which, if the system is stable with those patches can be deleted.  I wouldn't touch winsxs.

Comment: @Tofystedeth: I got the wrong directory, so I updated the answer with your remark.